# How to: check if a value has been used before, but only store a set number of them

Tags: c++

I have a function that's periodically called with a uint64_t and can be (virtually) any value, and I want to (approximately) check if the value has been used before, but only in the last N calls

So in other words, I know I need something like an `unordered_set` to check if it's been used before but I also want to start evicting things after `N` calls.

Is there an obvious way to do this or do I need to resort to using a combination of `std::queue` and `std::unordered_set` to determine what to remove.

(I can be flexible on what to remove, I just need to 'approximately' check if something has been used before without it necessarily being a FIFO removal)

Comment: What's the order of magnitude of `N` ?

Comment: You are looking for lru cach, and you are right to think that you basically need a queue and hash map https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lru-cache-implementation/amp/ somthing like this.

Comment: Always have to be careful when pointing people at Geeks for Geeks because they have a bad habit of telling people to do asinine stuff like `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;` Didn't inspect the rest of the code for correctness.

Comment: A simple `uint64_t[N]` array will typically suffice, unless `N` is huge. Otherwise, just use something like `if (my_unordered_set.size() == N) my_unordered_set.erase(my_unordered_set.begin());` before adding a number to `my_unordered_set`